# Is it possible to change configuration ui mode programmatically?

Tags: android, android-resources

I am developing an Android application that should work on both types of devices: phone, tv and tv box. To do this, I created resources with a TV modifier (for example, textSizes in dimens that will change automatically depending on the uimode), but the problem is that TV  boxes use mobile insead of TV. How to change the uimode on app start in order to use dimens with tv modifer?

I've already tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
config.uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION
resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution! Maybe it would be helpful for someone!

So, I must put it into `attachBaseContext` instead of `onCreate`

```
override fun attachBaseContext(context: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context)

        if (context != null) {
            SettingsData.initDeviceType(context)

            if (SettingsData.deviceType == DeviceType.TV) {
                resources.configuration.uiMode = uiMode
                resources.configuration.setTo(resources.configuration)
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, having switched to another device mode, you have to reload an activity. I've tried `finish() StartActivity(intent)`, but it doesn't work properly. So to fix it up I use **ProcessPhoenix** lib:

```
    fun refreshActivity() {
        ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(this)
    }
```

**Warning!** If you are using `setRequestedOrientation` in your `MainActivity`, it could trigger configuration to change with old `uimode`.